# AWK performance while processing big files

Tags: bash, awk

I have an awk script that I use for calculate how much time some transactions takes to complete. The script gets the unique ID of each transaction and stores the minimum and maximum timestamp of each one. Then it calculates the difference and at the end it shows those results that are over 60 seconds.

It works very well when used with some thousand (200k) but it takes more time when used in real world. I tested it several times and it takes about 15 minutes to process about 28 million of lines. Can I consider this good performance or it is possible to improve it?

I'm open to any kind of suggestion.

Here you have the complete code

```
zgrep -E "\(([a-z0-9]){15,}:" /path/to/very/big/log |  awk '{
gsub("[()]|:.*","",$4); #just removing ugly chars
++cont
min=$4"min" #name for maximun value of current transaction
max=$4"max" #same as previous, just for readability 
split($2,secs,/[:,]/) #split hours,minutes and seconds
seconds = 3600*secs[1] + 60*secs[2] + secs[3] #turn everything into seconds
if(arr[min] > seconds || arr[min] == 0)
  arr[min]=seconds
if(arr[max] < seconds)
   arr[max]=seconds
dif=arr[max] - arr[min]
if(dif > 60)
  result[$4] = dif
}
END{
for(x in result)
   print x" - "result[x]
print ":Processed "cont" lines"
}'
```

Comment: About the edit: the part  print "new MO found! "name " start at "seconds (the block where I assign a value to the min[name]) is only executed ~=800 times, but at the end, it reports that the length of min is about 80k, which is the number of the non value indexes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the dif every time you read a record. Just do it once in the END section.

You don't need that cont variable, just use NR.

You dont need to populate min and max separately string concatenation is slow in awk.

You shouldn't change $4 as that will force the record to be recompiled.

Try this:

```
awk '{
    name = $4
    gsub(/[()]|:.*/,"",name); #just removing ugly chars

    split($2,secs,/[:,]/) #split hours,minutes and seconds
    seconds = 3600*secs[1] + 60*secs[2] + secs[3] #turn everything into seconds

    if (NR==1) {
        min[name] = max[name] = seconds
    }
    else {
        if (min[name] > seconds) {
            min[name] = seconds
        }
        if (max[name] < seconds) {
            max[name] = seconds
        }
    }
}

END {
    for (name in min) {
        diff = max[name] - min[name]
        if (diff > 60) {
            print name, "-", diff
        }
    }
    print ":Processed", NR, "lines"
}'
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I will check it tomorrow and let you know. Thank you very much

Comment: Hello Ed, after trying your solution I have a couple of comments: The NR==1 does not makes sense in my scenario because any line can be the first line of a transaction. After erasing that line and using min[name]==0 as starter I made some test and I got similar results: # your proposal: real 13m45.390s user 18m9.014s# # my code: real 13m0.101s user 17m47.016s # Additionally, could you please explain me why modifying $4 makes awk to recompile the whole line? Is just because it is I suppose

Comment: Test for `min[name]==""`, not `==0`. It's just one of the functionalities of awk that modifying a field re-compiles the record replacing FS with OFS. When doing the timing - make sure you run each example 3 times and take the result of the third run of each so caching isn't a factor. Mine should have run noticably faster than yours since I'm only calculating dif once per final min/max pair and not for every single line and not recompiling the record and removing the increment of `cont`. Are you including the `zgrep` in the run? Is it possible that's what's using up all the time?

Comment: Thank you for your great help. I agree that your implementation should be faster since there is a difference of millions of operations.Do you mean I should run each test tree times consecutively or just tree times? Yes, I'm including zgrep in all the runs. I'm starting to think this is the bottleneck since all the scripts takes similar time to run. I need zgrep to select only the lines that corresponds to transactions. Would be faster if I do this check inside awk? I don't understand why it is so slow.When I use zgrep with a single string is just a matter of seconds and it reads all lines too.

Comment: I mean run one script 3 times and take the 3rd time output for it, then do the same for the other script. Idk about zgrep but you could save it's output in a file and then run awk on that file to separate the durations.

Answer (score 2):

After making some test, and with the suggestions gave by Ed Morton (both for code improvement and performance test) I found that the bottleneck was the zgrep command. Here is an example that does several things:

- Check if we have a transaction line (first if)
- Cleans the transaction id
- checks if this has been already registered (second if) by checking if it is in the array
- If is not registered then checks if it is the appropriate type of transaction and if so it registers the timestamp in second
- If is already registered saves the new time-stamp as the maximun
- After all it makes the necessary operations to calculate the time difference

Thank you very much to all that helped me.

```
zcat /veryBigLog.gz |  awk '
{if($4 ~ /^\([:alnum:]/ ){
    name=$4;gsub(/[()]|:.*/,"",name);
    if(!(name in min)){
        if($0 ~ /TypeOFTransaction/ ){
          split($2,secs,/[:,]/) 
          seconds = 3600*secs[1] + 60*secs[2] + secs[3] 
          max[name] = min[name]=seconds
          print lengt(min) "new "name " start at "seconds
       }
       }else{ 
            split($2,secs,/[:,]/)
            seconds = 3600*secs[1] + 60*secs[2] + secs[3]
            if( max[name] < seconds) max[name]=seconds
            print name " new max " max[name]
        }
        }}END{
            for(x in min){
                dif=max[x]- min[x]
                print max[x]" max - min "min[x]" : "dif
            }
            print "Processed "NR" Records"
            print "Found "length(min)" MOs" }'
```